# Error with arm-trusted-firmware compilation when built by cross toolchain

Tags: arm64, gcc7

I am working on rcar gen 3 platform from Renesas and particularly on arm-trusted-firmware level.

```
    1. bootparam_sa0.srec Loader(Boot parameter)                <======= arm-trusted-firmware
    2. bl2-m3ulcb.srec Loader                                   <======= arm-trusted-firmware
    3. cert_header_sa6.srec Loader(Certification)               <======= arm-trusted-firmware
    4. bl31-m3ulcb.srec ARM Trusted Firmware                    <======= arm-trusted-firmware
    5. tee-m3ulcb.srec Open Portable Trusted OS                 <======= optee-os
    6. u-boot-elf.srec U-Boot                                   <======= u-boot
```

I built BL31 by command with Gcc v5.4

***$ make ARCH=aarch64 CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu- PLAT=rcar LSI=M3 RCAR_GEN3_ULCB=1 RCAR_LOSSY_ENABLE=1 RCAR_DRAM_SPLIT=2 PMIC_LEVEL_MODE=0 bl31***

But I ran into the below err:

```
"
Including services/spd/opteed/opteed.mk
 AS bl31/aarch64/runtime_exceptions.S
bl31/aarch64/runtime_exceptions.S: Assembler messages:
bl31/aarch64/runtime_exceptions.S:183: Error: non-constant expression in ".if" statement
bl31/aarch64/runtime_exceptions.S:191: Error: non-constant expression in ".if" statement
bl31/aarch64/runtime_exceptions.S:196: Error: non-constant expression in ".if" statement
bl31/aarch64/runtime_exceptions.S:201: Error: non-constant expression in ".if" statement
bl31/aarch64/runtime_exceptions.S:215: Error: non-constant expression in ".if" statement
bl31/aarch64/runtime_exceptions.S:219: Error: non-constant expression in ".if" statement
bl31/aarch64/runtime_exceptions.S:223: Error: non-constant expression in ".if" statement
bl31/aarch64/runtime_exceptions.S:227: Error: non-constant expression in ".if" statement
bl31/aarch64/runtime_exceptions.S:241: Error: non-constant expression in ".if" statement
bl31/aarch64/runtime_exceptions.S:245: Error: non-constant expression in ".if" statement
bl31/aarch64/runtime_exceptions.S:249: Error: non-constant expression in ".if" statement
bl31/aarch64/runtime_exceptions.S:257: Error: non-constant expression in ".if" statement
bl31/aarch64/runtime_exceptions.S:271: Error: non-constant expression in ".if" statement
bl31/aarch64/runtime_exceptions.S:275: Error: non-constant expression in ".if" statement
bl31/aarch64/runtime_exceptions.S:279: Error: non-constant expression in ".if" statement
bl31/aarch64/runtime_exceptions.S:287: Error: non-constant expression in ".if" statement
Makefile:556: recipe for target 'build/rcar/release/bl31/runtime_exceptions.o' failed
make: *** [build/rcar/release/bl31/runtime_exceptions.o] Error 1
"
```

Same error: https://github.com/ARM-software/tf-issues/issues/417

The assembly code is correct and is apparently not the problem.

It seemed that it depends on Compiler. I was trying to install gcc/g++ 7.4 cross:

http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gcc-7-cross/gcc-7-aarch64-linux-gnu_7.4.0-1cross1_amd64.deb

http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gcc-7-cross/g++-7-aarch64-linux-gnu_7.4.0-1cross1_amd64.deb

on Ubuntu 16.04, and modified the Makefile to used gcc-7 (cross), g++-7 (cross), but still had this error. How can I overcome this err ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could stop using the toolchains that are provided with your Linux distribution, and  start using a Linaro toolchain instead:

```
wget https://releases.linaro.org/components/toolchain/binaries/latest-7/aarch64-elf/gcc-linaro-7.4.1-2019.02-x86_64_aarch64-elf.tar.xz
tar Jxf gcc-linaro-7.4.1-2019.02-x86_64_aarch64-elf.tar.xz -C /opt

git clone https://github.com/renesas-rcar/arm-trusted-firmware arm-trusted-firmware-renesas
cd arm-trusted-firmware-renesas
make ARCH=aarch64  CROSS_COMPILE=/opt/gcc-linaro-7.4.1-2019.02-x86_64_aarch64-elf/bin/aarch64-elf- PLAT=rcar LSI=M3 RCAR_GEN3_ULCB=1 RCAR_LOSSY_ENABLE=1 RCAR_DRAM_SPLIT=2 PMIC_LEVEL_MODE=0 bl31 
Including services/spd/opteed/opteed.mk
  CC      drivers/arm/gic/common/gic_common.c
  CC      drivers/arm/gic/v2/gicv2_main.c
  CC      drivers/arm/gic/v2/gicv2_helpers.c
  CC      plat/common/plat_gicv2.c
  CC      drivers/arm/cci/cci.c
  CC      plat/renesas/rcar/bl31_rcar_setup.c
  CC      plat/renesas/rcar/rcar_pm.c
  CC      plat/renesas/rcar/rcar_sip_svc.c
  CC      plat/renesas/rcar/drivers/board/board.c
  CC      plat/renesas/rcar/drivers/dramconf/dramconf.c
  CC      plat/renesas/rcar/drivers/memdrv/rcar_printf.c
  CC      plat/renesas/rcar/rcar_topology.c
  CC      plat/renesas/rcar/aarch64/rcar_common.c
  CC      plat/renesas/rcar/aarch64/rcar_drivers_common.c
  CC      plat/renesas/rcar/drivers/pwrc/rcar_pwrc.c
  CC      plat/renesas/rcar/drivers/cpld/ulcb_cpld.c
  CC      plat/renesas/rcar/drivers/wait/micro_wait.c
  CC      plat/common/plat_psci_common.c
  CC      plat/compat/plat_pm_compat.c
  CC      plat/compat/plat_topology_compat.c
  CC      bl31/bl31_main.c
  CC      bl31/interrupt_mgmt.c
  CC      bl31/bl31_context_mgmt.c
  CC      common/runtime_svc.c
  CC      services/arm_arch_svc/arm_arch_svc_setup.c
  CC      services/std_svc/std_svc_setup.c
  CC      lib/el3_runtime/cpu_data_array.c
  CC      lib/el3_runtime/aarch64/context_mgmt.c
  CC      lib/cpus/errata_report.c
  CC      lib/psci/psci_off.c
  CC      lib/psci/psci_on.c
  CC      lib/psci/psci_suspend.c
  CC      lib/psci/psci_common.c
  CC      lib/psci/psci_main.c
  CC      lib/psci/psci_setup.c
  CC      lib/psci/psci_system_off.c
  CC      lib/psci/psci_mem_protect.c
  CC      lib/locks/bakery/bakery_lock_coherent.c
  CC      lib/extensions/spe/spe.c
  CC      services/spd/opteed/opteed_common.c
  CC      services/spd/opteed/opteed_main.c
  CC      services/spd/opteed/opteed_pm.c
  CC      common/bl_common.c
  CC      common/tf_log.c
  CC      common/tf_printf.c
  CC      common/tf_snprintf.c
  CC      plat/common/plat_bl_common.c
  CC      plat/common/plat_log_common.c
  CC      plat/common/aarch64/plat_common.c
  CC      lib/stdlib/abort.c
  CC      lib/stdlib/assert.c
  CC      lib/stdlib/exit.c
  CC      lib/stdlib/mem.c
  CC      lib/stdlib/printf.c
  CC      lib/stdlib/putchar.c
  CC      lib/stdlib/puts.c
  CC      lib/stdlib/sscanf.c
  CC      lib/stdlib/strchr.c
  CC      lib/stdlib/strcmp.c
  CC      lib/stdlib/strlen.c
  CC      lib/stdlib/strncmp.c
  CC      lib/stdlib/strnlen.c
  CC      lib/stdlib/subr_prf.c
  CC      lib/stdlib/timingsafe_bcmp.c
  CC      plat/renesas/rcar/drivers/iic_dvfs/iic_dvfs.c
  CC      lib/xlat_tables_v2/aarch64/xlat_tables_arch.c
  CC      lib/xlat_tables_v2/xlat_tables_internal.c
  AS      lib/cpus/aarch64/aem_generic.S
  AS      lib/cpus/aarch64/cortex_a53.S
  AS      lib/cpus/aarch64/cortex_a57.S
  AS      plat/renesas/rcar/drivers/memdrv/rcar_console.S
  AS      plat/renesas/rcar/aarch64/rcar_helpers.S
  AS      plat/renesas/rcar/drivers/pwrc/rcar_call_sram.S
  AS      bl31/aarch64/bl31_entrypoint.S
  AS      bl31/aarch64/runtime_exceptions.S
  AS      bl31/aarch64/crash_reporting.S
  AS      plat/common/aarch64/platform_mp_stack.S
  AS      lib/el3_runtime/aarch64/cpu_data.S
  AS      lib/cpus/aarch64/cpu_helpers.S
  AS      lib/locks/exclusive/aarch64/spinlock.S
  AS      lib/psci/aarch64/psci_helpers.S
  AS      lib/el3_runtime/aarch64/context.S
  AS      lib/cpus/aarch64/wa_cve_2017_5715_bpiall.S
  AS      lib/cpus/aarch64/wa_cve_2017_5715_mmu.S
  AS      services/spd/opteed/opteed_helpers.S
  AS      common/aarch64/debug.S
  AS      lib/aarch64/cache_helpers.S
  AS      lib/aarch64/misc_helpers.S
  AS      plat/common/aarch64/platform_helpers.S
  AS      plat/compat/aarch64/plat_helpers_compat.S
  PP      bl31/bl31.ld.S
  LD      build/rcar/release/bl31/bl31.elf
  SREC    build/rcar/release/bl31.srec
  BIN     build/rcar/release/bl31.bin

Built build/rcar/release/bl31.bin successfully

  OD      build/rcar/release/bl31/bl31.dump
```